Flink sql running into an error while task manager crash : Could not restore keyed state backend for KeyedProcessOperator
Flink version : 1.19.0
We use flink sql, which using kafka connector to read from 7 different kafka topics and join between them to produce a final document, which is sent to another topic using upsert kafka connector.
Our state size is about 800 GB. Job runs just fine all the time.  The issue when one of the task manager dies. Job can't restore from the checkpoint. We have seens this error only for jobs with such huge state size.
Exception i see, i dont see anything logs in the job manager. What could be happening here ?
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreStateAndGates(StreamTask.java:799)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$restoreInternal$3(StreamTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:753)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:712)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:751)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for KeyedProcessOperator_960eab67cc3cec65f2a52f365aabc2cb_(11/32) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:399)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:180)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Caught unexpected exception.
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$3(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:393)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:137)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateDownloader.downloadDataForStateHandle(RocksDBStateDownloader.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateDownloader.lambda$null$0(RocksDBStateDownloader.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.ThrowingRunnable.lambda$unchecked$0(ThrowingRunnable.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:150)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:266)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:74)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:97)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBStateDownloader.downloadDataForStateHandle(RocksDBStateDownloader.java:162)
    ... 6 more


